# How to find lines containing a string in linux

Tags: linux, string, file, search

I have a file in Linux, I would like to display lines which contain a specific string in that file, how to do this?

Comment: `man grep` tells you what you want.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

The usual way to do this is with [`grep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep), which uses a [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) pattern to match lines:

```
grep 'pattern' file
```

Each line which matches the pattern will be output. If you want to search for fixed strings only, use `grep -F 'pattern' file`. `fgrep` is shorthand for `grep -F`.

---

You can also use [`sed`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed):

```
sed -n '/pattern/p' file
```

---

Or [`awk`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/awk):

```
awk '/pattern/' file
```

Comment: addition grep -rn 'string' /path/ if you want to search a string in a folder in which file including and line number

Answer (score 18):

Besides `grep`, you can also use other utilities such as `awk` or `sed`

Here is a few examples. Let say you want to search for a string `is` in the file named `GPL`.

**Your sample file**

```
$ cat -n GPL 
     1    The GNU General Public License is a free, copyleft license for
     2    The licenses for most software and other practical works are designed
     3  the GNU General Public License is intended to guarantee your freedom to
     4  GNU General Public License for most of our software;
```

**1. grep**

```
$ grep is GPL 
  The GNU General Public License is a free, copyleft license for
the GNU General Public License is intended to guarantee your freedom to
```

**2. awk**

```
$ awk /is/ GPL 
  The GNU General Public License is a free, copyleft license for
the GNU General Public License is intended to guarantee your freedom to
```

**3. sed**

```
$ sed -n '/is/p' GPL
  The GNU General Public License is a free, copyleft license for
the GNU General Public License is intended to guarantee your freedom to
```

Answer (score 15):

/tmp/myfile

```
first line text
wanted text
other text
```

the command

```
$ grep -n "wanted text" /tmp/myfile | awk -F  ":" '{print $1}'
2
```

The `-n` switch to grep prepends any matched line with the line number (followed by `:`), while the second command uses the colon as a column separator (`-F ":"`) and prints out the first column of any line. The final result is the list of **line numbers** with a match.

Comment: An answer should contain explanation of the given command. Besides, the OP was probably asking for the actual line, not the line number

Comment: @Ilario Alright, feel free to give your edit contribution to the answer.

Answer (score 8):

The [grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?egrep) family of commands (incl egrep, fgrep) is the usual solution for this.

```
$ grep pattern filename
```

If you're searching source code, then [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) may be a better bet. It'll search subdirectories automatically and avoid files you'd normally not search (objects, SCM directories etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Write the queue job information in long format to text file

`qstat -f > queue.txt`

Grep job names

`grep 'Job_Name' queue.txt`